# Android: any-screen capture without ROOT and constant USB connection

Tags: android

I'm trying to make an app that takes a video capture of the screen by taking individual snapshots. I've been looking into taking the snapshot without root, and seems that most solutions use ddmlib and require the device to be constantly connected via USB.

The only solution that doesn't require root and a constant usb connection is the android screenshot library. However, from the forum comments as well as my experience with the demo app, this library doesn't work very reliably/consistently.

Is there any other solution?

Note: I've also looked at the Noroot Screenshotit app (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.edwardkim.android.screenshotitfullnoroot&hl=en), and seem like they have a similar approach to the android screenshot library, but have no idea how they make it more reliable. If anyone has an idea, that would be helpful as well.

Thanks

Edit: We've already got the USB-connected implementation, but we want to be able to do it on the device alone, without needing any connection to another PC.

Comment: adb can be connected via bluetooth or wifi as well as USB, so you can use that.  Otherwise no, apps can't access the screen when other apps are in the foreground for security purposes.

Comment: ok, thanks. We've already got the USB-connected implementation, but we want to be able to do it on the device alone, without any connection to another PC.

Answer (score 0):

As of Android 5.0+, you can use the new functionality in the SDK called [media projections](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/package-summary.html) to do screen capture without root privileges or a USB connection.  There is sample code by Google available [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ScreenCapture).